# How to enclose terminal symbols within circles and/or nice oval boxes in a syntax diagram built using syntax.sty?

Tags: diagrams, syntax

I hope you can help me again.

I want to use the `syntax` package to build syntax diagrams, but I want to enclose non-terminal symbols in boxes and terminal symbols in circles or well-formed oval boxes (or rounded boxes). Here is my MWE built using `\ovalbox` from the package `fancybox`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[rounded, nounderscore]{syntax}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{syntdiag}
\fbox{ident} \ovalbox{(}
\begin{rep} \begin{stack} \\
\fbox{type} \begin{stack} \\ \fbox{ident} \end{stack}
\end{stack} \\ \ovalbox{,} \end{rep}
\begin{stack} \\ \ovalbox{...} \end{stack} \ovalbox{)}
\end{syntdiag}

\end{document}
```

Yes, it looks awful. I know it can be improved, but I don't know how. Do you know what commands I should use to enclose terminal symbols in circles or oval boxes? I have not found a solution in the documentation of `syntax.sty` and, since I am using `pdflatex`, I would not like to use `pstricks` and `dvi2ps` because my figures might mess up.

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to achieve a beautiful design when boxing the expressions; in the following code I used `TikZ` to define two kinds of frames (a circular one and a rectangular one); the code exhibits a comparison between a diagram drawn as suggested in the `syntax` documentation, the same diagram using `\fbox` and `\ovalbox`, and the same diagram using the frames defined with `TikZ`; in the last diagram the lengths `\sdtokskip and`\sdmidskip` were redefined in an effort to improve the visual appearance:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[rounded, nounderscore]{syntax}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\MyOval[1]{\tikz[baseline=-3pt]%
  \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=15pt] {#1};}
\newcommand\MyRect[1]{\tikz[baseline=-3pt]%
  \node[draw,rectangle,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10pt] {#1};}

\begin{document}

\begin{syntdiag}
<ident> ‘(’
\begin{rep} \begin{stack} \\
<type> \begin{stack} \\ <ident> \end{stack}
\end{stack} \\ ‘,’ \end{rep}
\begin{stack} \\ ‘...’ \end{stack} ‘)’
\end{syntdiag}

\begin{syntdiag}
\fbox{ident} \ovalbox{(}
\begin{rep} \begin{stack} \\
\fbox{type} \begin{stack} \\ \fbox{ident} \end{stack}
\end{stack} \\ \ovalbox{,} \end{rep}
\begin{stack} \\ \ovalbox{...} \end{stack} \ovalbox{)}
\end{syntdiag}

\begin{syntdiag}[\setlength\sdtokskip{12pt},\setlength\sdmidskip{12pt}]
\MyRect{ident} \MyOval{(}
\begin{rep} \begin{stack} \\
\MyRect{type} \begin{stack} \\ \MyRect{ident} \end{stack}
\end{stack} \\ \MyOval{,} \end{rep}
\begin{stack} \\ \MyOval{...} \end{stack} \MyOval{)}
\end{syntdiag}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion, all three look ugly; perhaps you could consider using `TikZ` to draw the diagrams from scratch?

Here's a very basic design using TikZ and the result is better:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine[-4\pgflinewidth]
{dou}{dou}{latex reversed}{latex}{latex}{latex reversed}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
  terminal/.style={draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=2pt,
    minimum size=18pt},
  nonterminal/.style={draw,fill=white,rectangle,inner sep=2pt,
    minimum size=10pt},
  y=0.5cm]

\draw[dou-dou] (0,0) -- node[nonterminal] (id1) {ident} (2,0) -- node[terminal] (ob) {(} (2.5,0) 
  -- (10.5,0) -- node[terminal] (cb) {)}  (\textwidth,0) ;

\node[nonterminal] at (4.5,-1) (ty) {type};
\node[terminal] at (9.7,-1) (ell) {...};
\node[nonterminal] at (6.5,-2) (id2) {ident};
\node[terminal] at (6,1) (co) {,};

\draw (3.5,0) |- (ty) -| (8,0);
\draw (5.5,-1) |- (id2) -| (7.5,-1);
\draw (9,0) |- (ell) -| (10.4,0);
\draw (3,0) |- (co) -| (8.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]